# Gradle always executes task

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradlew

I added 3 configurations to Gradle flavors. And I add some zip dependencies to them. I unzip this zip file after preBuild. 
The problem is my unzip task always executes even gradle file or dependencies not changed. This unzip task takes time and I'm developing ndk application. Every time when I change my static libraries with my unzip task, gradle thinks that libraries changed so it build again.

I want to block execution of unzip task if gradle file not changed. This looks like a little cache mechanism. Here is my gradle task.

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0"
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'src/main/libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    alphaCompile 'my alpha release static library from private maven repository in zip type'
    betaCompile 'my beta release static library from private maven repository in zip type'
    prodCompile 'my prod release static library from private maven repository in zip type'
}


task unzip(group: "Static Libraries", description: "Unzip all static libraries") {
    doFirst{
        // get zip files from configurations
        // unzip and move static libraries to destination folder
        }
    }
}
preBuild.finalizedBy (unzip)
```

Comment: You are excluding the most important part from your question - the body of the `doFirst` method. You are not declaring any inputs/outputs to your task, so Gradle can not know about its up-to-date checking.

Comment: Okay I understand I need to learn gradle lifecycle. I looked gradle documentation but It looks complicated.Can tell me how can I define i/o to my custom task with doFisrt()?

Comment: You are going to want to define your task _configuration_ in the `{ }` block for task definition. This part is executed in the _configuration_ phase. If you define configuration there you are going to run into problems (see [this page in the User Guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/potential_traps.html#mkdirTrap)). I'll work on answering the question in a little bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to give you an exact answer because you have excluded the code in your `doFirst` block, but it looks like you could leverage the [`Copy`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html) task if you are just getting configuration files and then unzipping them somewhere else:

```groovy
tasks.create('unzip', Copy) {
  dependsOn configurations.alphaCompile
  from {
    project.configurations.alphaCompile.collect { zipTree(it) }
  }
  into project.file("${project.buildDir}/unzipDir/")
}
```

If you do need to define a custom task, you need to register inputs and outputs during the [*configuration*](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#sec:build_phases) phase by using [`Task.getInputs()`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Task.html#getInputs()) and [`Task.getOutputs()`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Task.html#getOutputs()) so that Gradle can check from before execution.

Comment: Okay I understand what I missed. But now gradle throws exception: Could not find method unzip() for arguments [unzip, class org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy, build_4mrnler6ctu70k48fsy3b1k5d$_run_closure5@1d372b43] on project

Comment: Do you have quotes around `unzip`? I am creating the task here using the task container rather than the way you speed in your example.

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. Your answer is correct it helped so much. Thank you! :)